# How to print a message after checking through TestNG's Assert.assertEquals method?

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng, assert

I'm getting a string value from a function. Now I want to print a message saying whether expected string and actual string are different or not.

To compare these string I'm using TestNG's [`Assert.assertEquals`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

If strings are equal print --> Equal
Else print ---> not equal

Comment: I assume you’re using Java? But why do you want to print the results manually? Your IDE/build tool should give you the feedback you need, that is, which tests have passed and which have failed.

Comment: Yeah it gives. But I want to print these output into a document in a simple way

Comment: I think, if I use try-catch I might be able to do it. But I'm looking for a better way if there is any

Comment: Try-catch would work, but that’s cumbersome. Are you using JUnit (4/5?)?

Comment: Im using testNG

Comment: Are you asking for refactoring advice or you want to build the code from scratch?

Comment: I just need the code to insert output result of assert.assertEquals method into a if else statement. (If it is possible)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to wrap the assertion within a try-catch block, something like:

```
try {
    Assert.assertEquals(actualString, expectedString);
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    System.out.println("Not equal");
    throw e;
}
System.out.println("Equal");
```

A more sophisticated solution would be to use TestNG's extension mechanism for [logging](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging):

> It's very easy to generate your own reports with TestNG with Listeners and Reporters:
>
> - **Listeners** implement the interface [`org.testng.ITestListener`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html) and are notified in real time of when a test starts, passes, fails, etc...
> - **Reporters** implement the interface [`org.testng.IReporter`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IReporter.html) and are notified when all the suites have been run by TestNG. The IReporter instance receives a list of objects that describe the entire test run.
>
> For example, if you want to generate a PDF report of your test run, you don't need to be notified in real time of the test run so you should probably use an `IReporter`. If you'd like to write a real-time reporting of your tests, such as a GUI with a progress bar or a text reporter displaying dots (".") as each test is invoked […], `ITestListener` is your best choice.

Comment: Do listeners or reporters have information about all assertions that passed in a given test methods?

Answer (score 4):

The best practice of **TestNg** behavior overriding is using so called listeners. For example you can override the dafault behavior of what is happenning when your assert fails. To do that you need to extend `TestListenerAdapter` class as it is shown below:

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

public class StringComparatorListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Not Equal");
        super.onTestFailure(iTestResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Equal");
        super.onTestSuccess(iTestResult);
    }
}
```

Now you should add the listener to your test. Either by configuring `testng.xml` or by adding listener straigt in the code. Below is the example of how to add the above listener to your code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;


@Listeners(test.StringComparatorListener.class)
public class TestChangeTestNgBehavior {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        String str = "One string";
        assertEquals("Other string", str);
    }

}
```

This is the minimal and complete example which you can run and test and amend according to your particular need.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to decorate `org.testng.Assert` with logging feature:

```
public class MyAssert {

   public static void assertEquals(String actualString, String expectedString) {
     try {
       org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(actualString, expectedString);
       log.trace("Equal");
     } catch (AssertionError e) {
       log.trace("Not equal");
       throw e;
     }
   }
}
```

You can decorate other assertion methods like `assertTrue`, `assertThat`, etc. in a similar way. Yes, the logic is the same to what others have proposed, but the difference is that you don't repeat same logging/printing logic in every test. That specifically makes sense when a test method contains multiple assertions (soft assertions in particular).

PS. Note, usage of `assertEquals` is discouraged in favour to `assertThat`.